# FFMPEG: How to output image2 format into a tcp/udp socket?

Tags: ffmpeg, rtsp

I've got ffmpeg to read some RTSP stream and output image2 format to stdout like so:

```
ffmpeg -rtsp_transport tcp -i  "rtsp:xxxxx" -f image2 -update 1 -
```

But stdout is not good enough for me.. I am trying to pass it to "push" it to some other process that I cannot "pipe" to ffmpeg due to some architecture constraints. I am running on Linux so I was hoping to simulate some tcp/udp socket via the file system e.g. /dev/somthing or similar. Alternatively, maybe it's possible to get ffmpeg to send the image directly to a given tcp/udp address? This didn't work though (ffmpeg expects a file output):

```
ffmpeg -rtsp_transport tcp -i  "rtsp:xxxxx" -f image2 -update 1 "udp://localhost:3333"
```

Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normal image2 muxer expects to write to one or more image files. Use the image2pipe muxer.

```
ffmpeg -rtsp_transport tcp -i  "rtsp:xxxxx" -f image2pipe "udp://localhost:3333"
```

(-update has no relevance when piping).

Comment: The data I'm getting on the udp port is different than when I read stdout. The jpeg decoder keeps failing on every frame "Error: SOI not found". The udp packet sizes also appear much smaller than when I get on stdout...

Comment: This works locally for me as a client command: `ffplay -i ip:port`. If that works, then it's an issue with your receiver. UDP packets will be 188 bytes. For stdout, ffmpeg will write 64K at a time, I believe. Check for packet loss, and reordering on the receiver. You can also consider using mkfifo and writing to that and using netcat to send that file to your client.

Comment: thanks, indeed the problem was the receiver, I needed to gather several packets and look for magic markers in order to build the frames (reference: rtsp-ffmpeg npm module)